# Library seach boxes not showing for some users

Tags: 2010, filter, library

I have a sharepoint library which includes a filter/search box for each field. The search boxes were built by a 3rd party so I'm not sure how they are programmed. They are view specific.
These boxes don't show up for a few of my staff, one of who (accounts officer) really need them to make her job less frustrating.
Myself and the IT manager are at a loss.
We use vmware vm's and the vm's I use and the accounts officers vm are provisioned from the same image so we can discount software issues.
We reset internet explorers settings on both my vm and hers which made no difference, I can still see and use the search boxes but she cannot.
We tried chrome, in chrome I can see these boxes but she cannot.
The search boxes appear at the top of each field in the library but under the field name.
I'm just looking for somewhere to look to try and solve this, any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given these search boxes are from a third party, it's possible they may require some permissions she's lacking. Try elevating her permissions to site admin temporarily and see if that makes a difference. If it does, you just need to hunt down what she needs additional access to.

Comment: Thanks for that, I checked and she's site owner already which is the same level as myself. Other staff who have lower permissions have access.
I've been trying to find the coding for the search boxes through sharepoint designer but I haven't had any luck so far.